# Analytical tools to analyze the characteristics of a data manifold

Tags: manifold-learning

In the paper "**Emergence of separable manifolds in deep language representations**," the authors use an analytical tool called **Mean Field Theoretic Manifold Analysis** to measure the manifold capacity, manifold dimension, manifold radius, and center correlations.

I'm wondering if there are any other similar tools to analyze the characteristic of a data manifold? Does anyone know such a tool?

[Mamou, Jonathan, et al. "Emergence of separable manifolds in deep language representations." arXiv preprint arXiv:2006.01095 (2020).](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01095)